# How to view an image in new tab instead of download in NodeJS using Multer

Tags: node.js, multer

I'm using Multer and express to add image via a form. I have successfully created the file in an uploads folder. When I try to call the url it is being downloaded in a file format. I need to open it in a new tab based on mime type.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Below is my code:

```
 app.use('/images', express.static(__dirname + '/file/uploads/'));
```

Sample url:

```
 http://localhost:2020/images/b78339184694e2e6864a77d4f3067db5
```

Comment: Assuming you are storing image paths in the database.
 You have to convert your image path to `base 64` format in order to view it.

Comment: @mayankbisht could you share code snippet for the same.

Answer (score 0):

I added filename in my storage variable to achieve the required result.

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, __dirname+'/file/uploads/')
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
      console.log(file);
      var extArray = file.mimetype.split("/");
      var extension = extArray[extArray.length - 1];
      var name = crypto.randomBytes(10).toString('hex');
      cb(null, name + Date.now()+ '.' +extension)
    }
  });
```